# Git: Pull from remote and merge with local work

Tags: git

I'm in real trouble and need your help! After my HDD died I need to pull my latest work from my webserver and merge it with some local stuff I have backed up. However, I'm not a pro with git and don't want to mess up anything, that's why I created this topic. Let me explain the situation:

I'm working on a Laravel project but my HDD died and my latest work got lost. I have a two day old backup on my homeserver. But it doesn't include the latest work, the "vendor folder" (which is no problem, composer.json file is still there) and the ".git" file.

Now I want to pull the master branch from my webserver. However, I'm afraid I could mess something up. Can someone explain my how to get my master branch merged with my local work?

Thanks

Comment: did you pushed your latest work to remote before your HDD died?

Comment: Did your backup on the HDD include your `.git` directory?

Comment: Yes to both of you. I backed up my work. Two days after that my HDD died. But about ~2hrs before I pushed my latest work. So my backup on my homeserver is two days behind the work on my webserver. But as I said, my backup misses the ".git" directory. Thats my main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piecing together your narrative, you have:

- a homeserver with a non-git backup
- a webserver with your git repo (apparently *older* than the non-git backup)

To merge your backup with the git repo, just paste the backup files over a fresh clone.

- `git clone <path to webserver git> foo`
- paste the files into `foo`
- run `git status` in the `foo` directory

Comment: Yes, that worked for me! I had something in mind with pull. But clone was working. Thanks!